# DAX Measure if client has bought product A or B later

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot, power-bi-report-server

I need a DAX measure which shows me a flag (1 or 0) if a customer (DimCustomer) bought the product "A" someday (for the first time) and later (doesn't matter when) have bought or product "B" or "C".

Measure1: Flag (1 or 0) in their customer names if bought

Measure2: When was the first time that they bought product B or C

Basicly I have a FactSales, DimCustomer, DimDate and Dimproduct

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data to work with (and desired output)? It makes it much easier to answer if you have something concrete.

Comment: here are the tables:


KeyDate KeyCustomer KeyProduct Total
1 1 1 12,9
1 2 2 13
1 3 1 156,4
1 4 1 564,8
2 1 1 894,8
2 2 1 56,5
3 1 3 564,85
3 2 3 564,8
4 1 2 1325,6
4 2 2 132,3
 

KeyProduct Product
1 A
2 B
3 C
 

 

KeyCustomer Name
1 Jean
2 Mari
3 Lisa
4 Julian
 

Calendar
KeyDate Date
1 01/01/2018
2 02/01/2018
3 03/01/2018
4 04/01/2018

Comment: Please edit the post rather than putting the data in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a measure for sales or quantity sold. Here I use [Sales] as a stand-in.

```
Measure 1 =
    AND(
        FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE(
            DimDate[Date],
            CALCULATE(
                SELECTEDVALUE(DimProduct),
                FILTER(DimProduct, [Sales] > 0 )
            )
        ) = "A",
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES(DimProduct),
            FILTER(DimProduct, [Sales] > 0 )
        ) IN { "B", "C" }
    ) + 0
```

The first AND() argument iterates over every date, returns the first product with positive sales, and returns TRUE if product A. If multiple products were sold on the first day, a BLANK() is returned. The second argument to AND() evaluates whether Product B or C were ever purchased. Then, this TRUE/FALSE is converted to an integer by multiplying adding 0. If the first argument is TRUE, we know by logical inference that B or C was purchased subsequently, hence we only have to evaluate whether they were ever sold.

```
Measure 2 = 
    IF( [Measure 1] = 1, 
        FIRSTNONBLANK(
            DimDate[Date],
            CALCULATE( [Sales], DimProduct[product] IN {"B", "C"} ) > 0
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

If [Measure 1] is 1, we know the first product sold was A, and B or C was sold on a subsequent date. [Measure 2] iterates over all dates and identifies the first date where sales for product B or C were positive.