# Customers who bought and not bought some product in last 90 days

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I need a dax measure which shows me which customers bought products B and C in last 90 days.

And another one which shows me those whose bought products B and C in last 90 days.

(based in my filter date context)

Below is like it should be:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Here is a sample data if needed:

FactSales

```
KeyDate KeyCustomer KeyProduct  Total
1   1   1   12,9
1   2   2   13
1   3   1   156,4
1   4   1   564,8
2   1   1   894,8
2   2   1   56,5
3   1   2   564,85
3   2   3   564,8
4   1   1   1325,6
4   2   1   132,3
```

Customer

```
KeyCustomer Name
1   Jean
2   Mari
3   Lisa
4   Julian
5   Jhonny
```

Calendar

```
KeyDate Date
1   01/01/2018
2   02/01/2018
3   01/05/2018
4   01/08/2018
```

Product

```
KeyProduct  Product
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Comment: Looks like you left something out.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, The link didn't work... Here is my question at powerbi community:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Customers-who-bought-and-not-bought-some-product-in-last-90-days/m-p/496273#M231411

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DAX Measure if client has bought product A or B later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948638/dax-measure-if-client-has-bought-product-a-or-b-later)

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
IfBought = IF(
              COUNTROWS(
                  FILTER(FactSales,
                      RELATED('Product'[Product]) IN {"B", "C"} &&
                      RELATED('Calendar'[Date]) > TODAY() - 90)
                  ) > 0,
              1, 0)
```

Note that May 1st is longer than 90 days ago as of today though, so you won't get the result you asked for unless you change `90` to `114` or greater.

Comment: I can't use compared to today(), it has to be based on the filter date of the user:

Example: If the user is filtering 01/04/2018 in a report, he must see the results of 90 days before.

How would it be?

Comment: Then use `SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date])` instead of `TODAY()`.

Comment: I'm developing an analysis services tabular cube with 2016 version... There is no SELECTEDVALUE() function yet. Is there is any other way?

Comment: OK. Then try `MAX('Calendar'[Date])` or `EARLIER('Calendar'[Date])` if you're creating a calculated column.