# DAX - Inactive customers

Tags: ssas, powerbi, business-intelligence, dax, powerpivot

I have a measure like below which returns me all **active** customers who in the last 90 days bought product category  = 'A'

```
CustomersActive last 90 days:=
VAR Last90Days=
    MAX (DimDate[Date) - 90
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( FactSales[CustomerKey]);
        DimProduct[Category] = "A";
        FILTER (
            ALL (DimDate[Date);
             DimDate[Date] >= Last90Day
                && DimDate[Date]  <= MAX (DimDate[Date])
        )
    )
```

Now I need to create a measure **INACTIVE CUSTOMERS**:

Rule:

1. Make a list of all distinct customers whose someday bought product = "B" and the date of this was less than my actual filter date
2. Create a measure using also a distinct count of the last 90 days, but comparing the first list to my actual
3. If customer was in the first list (product B) and in my last 90 days (product A) is not appearing, then 1, else 0

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the prior questions in this chain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948638/dax-measure-if-client-has-bought-product-a-or-b-later and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968272/customers-who-bought-and-not-bought-some-product-in-last-90-days and explain how this question is different so that someone doesn't accidentally close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JasonAller this question is diferent because of new rules that I added up

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question, but rather a do-my-work-according-to-these-specifications post. Unless you show some effort and have specific questions about where you are getting stuck, people aren't likely to volunteer their time to help you.